# How do I embed CustomAction.CA.dll in to MSI?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I am using `wix toolset` to create MSI build.

Here is the Binary source in `Product.wxs` file.

```
    <Binary Id="BI.CA" 
         SourceFile="..\..\CustomAction\bin\$(var.Configuration)\CustomAction.CA.dll" />
```

MSI generated and works as expected in local but fails in build machine showing below error.

> Could not find CustomAction.CA.dll

I see that `CustomAction.CA.dll` is present in the build machine but not the path which I specified.

How do I embed this dll in to MSI?

**Update**

In build machine, I see the DLL here

> E:\BuildAgent\1\b\CustomAction.CA.dll"

Comment: Have you added a dll reference to your wix project?

Comment: I added as project reference

Comment: Did I send you my [WiX quick-start ad-hoc lunatic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130) before? Just heading out the door, there are [sample links](https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/tree/master/WiXSamples/CustomActionCSharp). Perhaps one of them has what you need. Otherwise, try [github.com](http://github.com).

Comment: Throwing in [this C++ CA answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925087/interrupt-installation-when-custom-action-returns-error). And [one more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285093/wix-custom-action-session-empty-and-error-on-deferred-action/54298965#54298965). Probably not useful, just lobbing some links on the run.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I made it work by adding $(TargetDir) in source file path. it worked now on build machine. but fails in local :)  anyways let me read your documents. Meanwhile now I am stuck with upgrade issues. Might create new quesiton if I do not find answer any where else. basically it says "anouther verson already exists" but I have changed verison number and GUID ID in new MSI

Answer (score 2):

When your DLL has the name `CustomAction.CA.dll` that should not be! Then you need to double the `CA` here `<Binary Id="BI.CA" 
         SourceFile="..\..\CustomAction\bin\$(var.Configuration)\CustomAction.CA.CA.dll" />`

The `CA` is an internal postfix for the DLL but the output / target of your Custom Action Library should not have it in the name.

You have two options:

a) Remove the CA from the output target in Custom Action project
b) Introduce a second CA in MSI-Project Binary Element

See also [How to execute a WiX custom action DLL file with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591700/how-to-execute-a-wix-custom-action-dll-file-with-dependencies)